# BitBucket не даёт склонировать мой репозиторий (я авторизован, SSH key добавлен)

Tags: git, bitbucket, ssh-key

Всем добрейшего времени суток.

Я авторизовался на BitBucket, добавил SSH ключ в свой аккаунт. Но! При этом он упорно пишет мне:

```
 Клонирование в «****»…
 Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
```

Я уже выполнил `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
Я уже настроил `git config --global user.name и git config --global user.email`

После выполнения команды `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` получаю ответ:

```
logged in as <mynickname>.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Смущает только последнее предложение, но как с ним бороться, я не имею представления... Жду помощи экспертов...

--updated--

После git -vT git@bitbucket.org, есть такая строчка:

```
Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
```

При этом новый ключ, который добавил я, начинается с символов:

```
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAAD...
```

Не знаю, правильное ли направления "рытья"...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67864/discussion-on-question-by-overtheman-bitbucket-----).

Comment: @Air нет не "вроде бы". А именно так.

Comment: Мистика какая-то. Приходится работать с BitBucket'om через https, при этом GitHub по SSH с этим же ключом работает, как часики.

Comment: Я до сих пор не придумал, что ещё может быть проблемой. Попробуйте, как советует в чате Александр, перегенерировать ключ и добавить в битбакет новую публичную часть.